# tensorflow: How to pass ith index of a tensor as input to fully connected layer?

Tags: tensorflow

One way to use attention, in tensorflow, is to directly use `tf.contrib.seq2seq.LuongAttention` or `tf.contrib.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention`.

But when my attention depends on the hidden states of encoder and output of decoder, things get little messy.

I'm trying use an attention given in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.02012.pdf (Section 3.2).

The equation is:

[image]

Where h stands for hidden state of encoder, d is for document, a is for answer, y is the output of decoder, s is the hidden state of decoder. `f` is the feedforward neural network.

If I would've known the value of `h` already I could just pass to `feed_dict` of `sess.run` one by one. But here a graph needs to be created.

One way I could do is:

```
tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(tf.concat((h_d[:,j,:], h_a, yt_1, st_1), 1),...)
```

for each *jth* index of h_d, but this is super expensive in terms of memory.

How to pass *jth* value of a tensor to `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected` while creating the graph itself ? Or is there a better way to do it ?